# RAM size dependent on memory type

Tags: memory, cpu

I have a laptop with the processor Intel [4450U](https://ark.intel.com/products/89611/Intel-Pentium-Processor-4405U-2M-Cache-2_10-GHz) installed. The specification says

> Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type) 32 GB

So what does the (dependent on memory type) actually mean for me? I would like to upgrade the PC with maximum available capacity, but I can't find any clues that would help me to understand what limits and for each type of RAM (DDR4 / DDR3L) are applied. Is there a way to figure it out?

Comment: So does your motherboard support DDR4 or DDR3?  Look at the current memory that's installed or the specifications for the exact laptop you purchased

Answer (score 2):

In this case the memory type probably refers to the type of memory chips accepted by the mainboard chosen by the system manufacturer than the speed or generation of the RAM.

When looking at the maximum memory a specific pre-built computer supports, you do not consult the CPU details, you consult the documentation for the system you purchased, where the limits will be spelled out.

Laptops typically use SO-DIMMs, which are smaller than the regular DIMMs used in desktop computers, and these have an accompanying limitation on the physical number of memory chips that will fit on them, and therefore the maximum amount of memory each SO-DIMM can hold.

Then, if the laptop only has 1 user-accessible memory slot, you are limited to only that one slot's maximum memory. If the laptop has two slots, then you get to put to SO-DIMMs in with an accompanying higher maximum memory in the computer.

So, what the CPU says and what you'll actually get are two different things. Consult your system documentation, not the CPU's technical specs.

Comment: Even I am confused.  The specifications specifically indicate DDR3 and DDR4 I seem to recall Haswell was the transition from DDR3 and DDR4

Comment: Oh, you know what, you're right. The LP beginning LPDDR3 meant I dismissed the rest of that line. Editing answer.

Comment: I even remember motherboards that had both but you couldn't use both at the same time (which clearly doesn't apply to the laptop) but an interesting factoid

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid I can't rely on any documentation regarding my laptop, since the manufacturer didn't include my configuration to official guide manual for the series. Technically there is a possibility to set 32 GB with say the kit (the laptop has two 204-pin SODIMM slots): https://www.amazon.com/Crucial-Single-PC3L-12800-SODIMM-CT204864BF160B/dp/B011ISG132?th=1 , but I don't know if there is any limitations in the PC world for the RAM capacity except CPU and the OS-capacity...

Comment: The keying for a memory chip will be unique to the type. DDR3 will not fit in a DDR4 slot. If you can get the motherboard model that may also help. BIOS may also limit the type and density of memory supported. 204 pin SODIMMs are DDR3, so that at least gets us the type supported by the motherboard.

Comment: @music2myear, correct. I can say that for sure that the laptop supports only DDR3L (it's written right on the motherboard), i'm also aware of supported freq (1600 mhz), the only question is whether it supports 32 gb or less.. The fact that firmware can limit the memory supported is new for me. Could you please elaborate on that? Did I understand correct that I probably limited in capacity of a single chip, but not the overall memory?

Comment: Either that is clearly documented in a public place, or you'll need to use trial and error. I'd also seriously question anyone using a laptop with an old processor like this wanting/needing more than 4 or 8GB of RAM total. What applications and tasks are is this laptop to be used for? Do you know that you need and can use more than 8GB of RAM?

Answer (score 2):

Some manufacturers allow higher densities of ECC (error-correcting code) RAM.  Dell Precision T1650s can support 16 GB of non-ECC, but up to 32 GB of ECC.  ECC was very important once for servers, but nowadays memory manufacturing is reliable enough that there's not much difference.  See https://blog.codinghorror.com/to-ecc-or-not-to-ecc/ .

Comment: That's a useful distinction, but would not be applicable in a laptop and when dealing with a non-server CPU such as OP is.